# Exception in for loop in scala code

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a small code snippet which will read data from spark driver argument and accordingly will loop and process its logic. Looking for your help.
For example, the inputs to the spark driver are 2012-01-01 and 6. Below is the code snippet. In the code iDate and iMonths are the inputs as above in spark driver.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, TimestampType}
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import _root_.filodb.spark._
import _root_.filodb.core.DatasetRef
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql._
import _root_.filodb.core.metadata.RichProjection
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import Array._
import java.util.Calendar
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import hc.implicits._

val args = sc.getConf.get("spark.driver.args").split("\\s+")
val iDate = args(0) + " 00:00:00"
val iMonths = args(1).toInt
val vDateFormatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
val vDateFormatYearMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM")
val vDateFormatDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa")
val vDateFrom = Calendar.getInstance()
val vDateFrom1 = Calendar.getInstance()
val vETLInsertDate = vDateFormatDateTime.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
vDateFrom1.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1)
val vMonthCheck = vDateFormatYearMonth.format(vDateFrom.getTime())+","+vDateFormatYearMonth.format(vDateFrom1.getTime())

try
{
val vBillMaxDate = if (iDate == "0001-01-01 00:00:00") {
hc.read.format("filodb.spark").option("database","*****").option("dataset","*****").load().filter(s"""yr_mon in (  ${vMonthCheck} )""").agg(max("*****").alias("max_date")).map { case Row (value) => value.asInstanceOf[java.sql.Timestamp]; }.first()
} else { 
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(iDate) 
}
val vMaxDate = vDateFormatDate.format(vBillMaxDate)
val vMaxYearMonth = vDateFormatYearMonth.format(vBillMaxDate).toString
vDateFrom.setTime(vDateFormatYearMonth.parse(vMaxYearMonth))

var vYearMonList = new ListBuffer[String]()
var vCount = 0

for (i <- 1 to iMonths)
{
val vInputYearMonth = vDateFormatYearMonth.format( vDateFrom.getTime() ).toString
println("Starting aggregation for : " + vInputYearMonth)
vYearMonList += vInputYearMonth
vDateFrom.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1)
vCount +=1
}
}catch{
case exp: Exception=>{
println("METADATA~error:"+ exp)
}
}finally{
FiloDriver.shutdown()
sc.stop()
sys.exit(0)
}
```

Getting below error:

```
vMonthCheck: String = 201801,201712
Starting aggregation for : 201201
Starting aggregation for : 201112
Starting aggregation for : 201111
Starting aggregation for : 201110
Starting aggregation for : 201109
Starting aggregation for : 201108
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:313)
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:311)
        at filodb.spark.FiloSetup$class.config(FiloSetup.scala:31)
        at filodb.spark.FiloDriver$.config(FiloSetup.scala:64)
        at filodb.spark.FiloSetup$class.columnStore(FiloSetup.scala:42)
        at filodb.spark.FiloDriver$.columnStore$lzycompute(FiloSetup.scala:64)
        at filodb.spark.FiloDriver$.columnStore(FiloSetup.scala:64)
        at filodb.spark.FiloDriver$.columnStore(FiloSetup.scala:64)
        at filodb.coordinator.CoordinatorSetup$class.shutdown(CoordinatorSetup.scala:83)
        at filodb.spark.FiloDriver$.shutdown(FiloSetup.scala:64)
```

**Updated Code for vMonthCheck variable to handle the scenario:**

```
val vMonthCheck = if (iDate == "0001-01-01 00:00:00") {vDateFormatYearMonth.format(vDateFrom.getTime())+","+vDateFormatYearMonth.format(vDateFrom1.getTime())} else {iDate.substring(0,4).concat(iDate.substring(5,7))}
```

Comment: This looks like a problem  with `filodb.spark.FiloDriver`, You might have a better chance if you try their issue tracker https://github.com/filodb/FiloDB/issues

Comment: Might be. But when my input date is 0001-01-01 (as per if condition), I do not get any error and everything works fine. So is this really a filo issue?

Comment: It looks like your `iDate` input parameter isn't parsed properly inside of the block:
`new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(iDate)`

Comment: Have made changes and its now working perfectly. Have Changed the vMonthCheck variable. Updated change in original query.